# Windows Server 2008 publishing ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I installed Windows 2008 wo/ Hyper-V to my server. I configured IIS 7 and start publishing HTML pages successfully. But when I want to publish (ASP.NET/C#) web site, I faced with an error which is;

' `It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.`'

Error line is; `<authentication mode="Forms">` . I configured IIS server and enables Forms authentication at authentication form, but still I cannot reach my web site. What can be the problem?

Thank you,

Jack Smith.